# how to cleanly yield an array from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, yield

This Javascript code gives a syntax error ("unexpected identifier") on the 
"yield" line in chrome version 70.0.3538.110:

```js
function foo() {
  var arr = [0];
  yield arr;
}
```

This has no error:

```js
function foo() {
  var arr = [0];
  return arr;
}
```

This also has no error:

```js
function foo() {
  var arr = [0];
  yield [arr];
}
```

I can yield the [] version and subscript it, but is there a cleaner way?

I want to yield the array many times during the execution of the function, as it gets mutated.

Comment: Are you using `yield` inside a generator [function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)? If you are attempting to use `yield` inside a normal `function` you will get an error. It is specifically used with generator functions.

Comment: Can you clarify how you would use `foo()` specifically? Methods like [next()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) to extract yielded values are specific to Generator functions. They return an object that looks like `{ value: 1, done: false }`. You wouldn't be able use `next()` on a non-Generator function.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky You are right: it needs to be a function*, and it is a dup of that question. Thanks! I'll close this as a dup.